# how to speedup when using QOpenGLWidget class to show point cloud?

Tags: c++, qt, qopenglwidget

when I use the qopenglwidget to show ply file, found the interface feedback with low efficiency when performing a mouse event.

Comment: are you repainting the canvas of the gl widget calling update() ?

Comment: Please add your code.